# How to collect objects to List based on properties of the class and then Map to HashMap in java 8 or 11?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, java-11

I have classes Similar to:

```java
class Response {
    Source source;
    Target target;
}

class Source {
    Long sourceId;
    String sourceName;
}

class Target {
    Long targetId;
    String targetName;
}
```

In the `Response, source(sourceId,sourceName)` could be the same for different target object.

I have entry in `Response` with these 4 properties `sourceId, sourceName, targetId, targetName`. I can have `sourceId`, `sourceName` the same on multiple rows but `targetId`, `targetName` will always be different.

I want to group all the target objects into the `List` for which source is the same.

I have `List` of Response objects and I am trying to perform `stream()` operation on it something like:

```java
Map<Source, List<Target>> res = results
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Response::getSource)
        //collect to map
```

So that my final output JSON would look something like:

```
"Response": { 
    "Source":       {  
        "sourceId":       "100",   
        "sourceName":      "source1",    
    }
    "Target": [{//grouping target objects with same source
        "targetId":       "10",   
        "targetName":      "target1",   
    }, {
        "targetId":       "20",   
        "targetName":      "target2",   
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `Source` needs to properly override `hashCode` and `equals` methods to be used as a key in Map.

However, another POJO should be implemented to contain the desired output:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
class Grouped {
    @JsonProperty("Source")
    Source source;

    @JsonProperty("Target")
    List<Target> target;
}
```

Then the list of responses may be converted as follows:

```java
List<Response> responses; // set up the input list

List<Grouped> grouped = responses.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Response::getSource,
        Collectors.mapping(Response::getTarget, Collectors.toList())
    )) // Map<Source, List<Target>> is built
    .entrySet()
    .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<Source, List<Target>>>
    .map(e -> new Grouped(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: just curious, can we use parallel streams here?

Comment: Yes, parallel streams can be used here.  However, as the first collection uses `HashMap`, the order of the keys is not guaranteed, and therefore the resulting list of `Grouped` is unsorted, that is, the order of its elements will be random.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to answer my similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70307068/) I am struck in the problem, I need grouping for object within object

Comment: @MohsinM,  you can check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70307951/13279831)

Comment: @MohsinM could you also upvote the answers that have been helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the sourceName is String (Due to the json)

Does it have to be a stream?

It can probably be done pretty easily like the following:

```
Map<Source,List<Target>> res= new HashMap<>();
for(Response response : results){
        List<Target> sourceTarget = res.computeIfAbsent(response.source, list -> new ArrayList<>());
        sourceTarget.add(response.target);
    }
```